# Can't eliminate pandas SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas

I tried many times, but I couldn´t avoid this warning in my code, when inserting the 'multiplier' column on 'ipcaMomSlice'. Any idea?

```
import pandas as pd

ipcaMom = bcbQuery(433)
ipcaMom['valor'] /= 100

initDate = "1995-01-01"

ipcaMomSlice = ipcaMom[initDate:]

ipcaMomSlice.loc[:,'multiplier'] = (1 + ipcaMomSlice['valor']).cumprod()
```

Comment: Why not create a column the normal way like this: `ipcaMomSlice['multiplier'] = (1 + ipcaMomSlice['valor']).cumprod()` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: Please provide the entire error output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this `ipcaMomSlice` to be it's own entity, and not refer back to `ipcaMom` (e.g. you don't want to assign a "multiplier" column to `ipcaMom` at all, and only want the "multiplier" on `ipcaMomSlice`) you'll need to tell pandas that `ipcaMomSlice` is no longer just a slice of a dataframe, but a full on independent subset. This is done with the `.copy()` method.

```
import pandas as pd

ipcaMom = bcbQuery(433)
ipcaMom['valor'] /= 100

initDate = "1995-01-01"

ipcaMomSlice = ipcaMom[initDate:].copy()

# no need for `.loc` in this assignment operation
ipcaMomSlice['multiplier'] = (1 + ipcaMomSlice['valor']).cumprod()
```

If however you're expecting "multiplier" to magically appear as a column in `ipcaMom` you'll need to combine your indexing from your `.loc`

```
import pandas as pd

ipcaMom = bcbQuery(433)
ipcaMom['valor'] /= 100

initDate = "1995-01-01"
ipcaMom.loc[initdate:, 'multiplier'] = (1 + ipcaMom.loc[initdate:, 'valor']).cumprod()
```

Comment: @DanielArges
Would you mind selecting my answer as correct if this worked for you so others can see this is an answered issue in the future?